# IHierarchicalEnumerable to SiteMapPath?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap, sitemappath

exists any simple method to use my IHierarchicalEnumerable class in SiteMapPath control?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how simple would it be but you need to implement a [sitemap provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sitemapprovider.aspx).